# Formatting strings in java

Tags: java, string

I want to print status messages into Console.

```
   System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 1", "[Success]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2 and some text", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2 and some very long text", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2 and some very very very long text", "[Failed]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
            System.out.format("%-60s%10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
```

But as you can see the second column messages are not formatted properly.

```
Status 1                                                     [Success]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2 and some text                                        [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2                                                     [Success]
Status 2 and some very long text                              [Failed]
Status 2                                                     [Success]
Status 2 and some very very very long text                    [Failed]
Status 2                                                     [Success]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
```

I want to print the messages like this:

```
Status 1                                                      [Success]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2 and some text                                        [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Success]
Status 2 and some very long text                              [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Success]
Status 2 and some very very very long text                    [Failed]
Status 2                                                      [Success]
Status 2                                                      [Failed]
```

How I can do this?

Comment: As a side note: it would be better to use `%n` instead of `\n` in the format string so that you get a newline sequence appropriate to the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add `"-"` to make the last field left-justified, as the first field? I suppose `"%-60s%-10s\n"` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this code

```
  System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 1", "[Success]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2 and some text", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2 and some very long text", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2 and some very very very long text", "[Failed]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Success]");
    System.out.format("%-60s%.10s\n", "Status 2", "[Failed]");
```

Comment: `%.10s` will let you print max 10 characters from passed String so maybe better idea would be just removing `.10` and using simple `%s`. But in case OP will want to add some other informations after `Success/Failed` column it is better to make sure that this column has fixed size. In case we want to print string value justified left  we should add `-` before column length.